# Highlighting table column td with different values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a html `<table>` showing logs, I would like to loop over the whole table highlighting any adjacent cells `<tr>` in a row with different values.

I am trying to compare any two values in a `<td>` in a particular row. I have managed to do something but only on 2 columns.

**Below is a html sample code of the table structure:**

```
    <table id="coa_history_data">
    <tr>
      <th>old Name</th>
      <th>New Name</th>
      <th>Old Phone</th>
      <th>New Phone</th>
      <th>Old Age</th>
      <th>New Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="data-in-table">
       <td>Alphy</td>
       <td>Alphy</td>
       <td>015</td> //should be highlited
       <td>016</td> //should be highlited
       <td>23</td> //should be highlited
       <td>24</td> //should be highlited
    </tr>
  <tr>
       <td>Tom</td>
       <td>Tom</td>
       <td>12</td>
       <td>12</td>
       <td>65</td> //should be highlited
       <td>30</td> //should be highlited
    </tr>
  <tr>
       <td>will</td>
       <td>will</td>
       <td>45</td>
       <td>45</td>
       <td>20</td>
       <td>20</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**And my JavaScript Code:**

```
 $("#coa_history_data tbody tr.data-in-table").each(function() {
      var $firstCell = $('td:eq(3)', this);
    var $thirdCell = $('td:eq(4)', this);

    if($firstCell.text() === $thirdCell.text()){

    }else{
       $firstCell.css('backgroundColor','yellow');
        $thirdCell.css('backgroundColor','yellow');  
    }
});
```

I would like some suggestions, how to handle it?

Comment: ...and you need to do it...where? On each cell? Full column? You may apply background to row or to each cell child of that row.

Comment: yes, I want to do it on each cell on a particular row

Comment: At the moment, it works only on two columns because only one row has the class "data-in-table"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest something like the following, in order to be independent of the number of columns.

http://jsfiddle.net/hA5G8/

**js**

```
$("#coa_history_data tbody tr.data-in-table").each(function () {

    $(this).find('td').each(function (index) {
        var currentCell = $(this);
        var nextCell = $(this).next('td').length > 0 ? $(this).next('td') : null;
        if (index%2==0&&nextCell && currentCell.text() !== nextCell.text()) {
            currentCell.css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');
            nextCell.css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');
        }
    });
});
```

**html**

```
<table id="coa_history_data">
    <tr class="data-in-table">
        <th>old Name</th>
        <th>New Name</th>
        <th>Old Phone</th>
        <th>New Phone</th>
        <th>Old Age</th>
        <th>New Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="data-in-table">
            <td>Alphy</td>
            <td>Alphy</td>
            <td>015</td>//should be highlited
            <td>016</td>//should be highlited
            <td>23</td>//should be highlited
            <td>24</td>//should be highlited</tr>
        <tr class="data-in-table">
            <td>Tom</td>
            <td>Tom</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>65</td>//should be highlited
            <td>30</td>//should be highlited</tr>
        <tr class="data-in-table">
            <td>will</td>
            <td>will</td>
            <td>45</td>
            <td>45</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres my solution:

```
<table id="coa_history_data">
    <tr>
      <th>old Name</th>
      <th>New Name</th>
      <th>Old Phone</th>
      <th>New Phone</th>
      <th>Old Age</th>
      <th>New Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="data-in-table">
       <td>Alphy</td>
       <td>Alphy</td>
       <td>015</td>
       <td>016</td>
       <td>23</td>
       <td>24</td>
    </tr>
  <tr class="data-in-table">
       <td>Tom</td>
       <td>Tom</td>
       <td>12</td>
       <td>12</td>
       <td>65</td>
       <td>30</td>
    </tr>
  <tr class="data-in-table">
       <td>will</td>
       <td>will</td>
       <td>45</td>
       <td>45</td>
       <td>20</td>
       <td>20</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JScript:

```
$("#coa_history_data tbody tr.data-in-table").each(function() {
      var $firstCell = $('td:eq(2)', this);
      var $secondCell = $('td:eq(3)', this);
      var $thirdCell = $('td:eq(4)', this);
      var $fourthCell = $('td:eq(5)', this);
    if($firstCell.text() != $secondCell.text()){
       $firstCell.css('backgroundColor','yellow');
        $secondCell.css('backgroundColor','yellow');  
    }
    if($thirdCell.text() != $fourthCell.text()){
       $thirdCell.css('backgroundColor','orange');
        $fourthCell.css('backgroundColor','orange');  
    }
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3CdyH/

Answer (score 0):

Ok you want to highlight particular fields `<td>` now i understand.

**The better solution is to do it at table creation time.**

**I have sure that this method is the better in performance, i have the tests here in** [JsPerf](http://jsperf.com/append-methods-performance)

So create your table this way:

**Important: of course that you will have dinamic values so put it on value variable inside the** `<td>`'s.

```
    var content = [];
    for (var i=0; i < len; i++){
      if (i==0) //i dont know what is your condition to the tr be 'data-in-table' so change if needs
        class = "data-in-table";
      content.push("<tr class='"+class+"'>         "+
                   "<td>will</td>                  "+
                   "<td>will</td>                  "+
                   "<td>"+value+"</td>             "+
                   "<td>"+value+"</td>             "+
                   "<td class=hlight>"+value+"</td>"+
                   "<td class=hlight>"+value+"</td>"+
                   "</tr>");
    }
    document.getElementById('your_table_wrapper').innerHTML = "<table id=coa_history_data>"+
                                                              "<tr>                       "+
                                                              "<th>old Name</th>          "+
                                                              "<th>New Name</th>          "+
                                                              "<th>Old Phone</th>         "+
                                                              "<th>New Phone</th>         "+
                                                              "<th>Old Age</th>           "+
                                                              "<th>New Age</th>           "+
                                                              "</tr>                      "+
                                                              "<tbody>                    "+
                                                              content.join('')+
                                                              "</tbody>                   "+
                                                              "</table>;
```

And use this CSS:

```
.hlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```